# What are differences between "let", "allow" and "permit"?

Tags: meaning, grammar

> Dad doesn't let me watch that program.

Can we use "allow" or "permit" instead of "let"? What are the differences in grammar? Which one is common use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All these sentences are valid:

> Dad doesn't *let me watch* that program.
>
> Dad doesn't *allow me to watch* that program.
>
> Dad doesn't *permit me to watch* that program.

Note the use of the full infinitive (*to* + verb) with *allow* and *permit.* This is in contrast to *let,* which doesn't require it.

All three of these verbs are in common use. There's no significant difference in the basic meanings, but the choice of which one to use is somewhat governed by the degree of formality of the situation: *let* is the least formal usage, and *permit* is the most formal.

Comment: _Mooom! Dad doesn't let me watch my program, his big butt keeps blocking it._ Also if I keep interrupting I do not let you watch your program.

Comment: In addition, _allow_ and _permit_ may be passivised, but not _let_ (in this sense): _Fishing [is] not allowed_ / _Fishing not permitted_.

Answer (score 2):

"Let" is a request in friendly way

Allow - Is up to individual's will & wish.

Permit - Authenticity of Law.

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think "let" is informal than "allow" and "permit". I use "allow" that means make something possible. For example; Dad allows me to watch that program. Dad makes watching TV possible or not. When using "let" Dad give you permission or not. It's not about creating conditions for watching TV. Permit is about formal permission. That's the way I use those words.